# Semantic UI Form validation not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, semantic-ui

I'm pretty new to Semantic UI and I'm a little rusty on my Javascript so please bear with me. I literally just copy pasted the code from the Semantic UI example on their website to see how their form validation works and for some reason it's not working with me. Could there be something I'm missing?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.2/semantic.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.10/components/form.css">
    <script src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"> </script>
    <script src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.10/semantic.min.js"> </script>
    <script src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.10/components/form.js"> </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <script>
  $('.ui.form')
    .form({
      fields: {
        name: {
          identifier: 'name',
          rules: [
            {
              type   : 'empty',
              prompt : 'Please enter your name'
            }
          ]
        },
        skills: {
          identifier: 'skills',
          rules: [
            {
              type   : 'minCount[2]',
              prompt : 'Please select at least two skills'
            }
          ]
        },
        gender: {
          identifier: 'gender',
          rules: [
            {
              type   : 'empty',
              prompt : 'Please select a gender'
            }
          ]
        },
        username: {
          identifier: 'username',
          rules: [
            {
              type   : 'empty',
              prompt : 'Please enter a username'
            }
          ]
        },
        password: {
          identifier: 'password',
          rules: [
            {
              type   : 'empty',
              prompt : 'Please enter a password'
            },
            {
              type   : 'minLength[6]',
              prompt : 'Your password must be at least {ruleValue} characters'
            }
          ]
        },
        terms: {
          identifier: 'terms',
          rules: [
            {
              type   : 'checked',
              prompt : 'You must agree to the terms and conditions'
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    })
  ;
</script>

<form class="ui form segment">
  <p>Tell Us About Yourself</p>
  <div class="two fields">
    <div class="field">
      <label>Name</label>
      <input placeholder="First Name" name="name" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <label>Gender</label>
      <select class="ui dropdown" name="gender">
        <option value="">Gender</option>
        <option value="male">Male</option>
        <option value="female">Female</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
<div class="two fields">
  <div class="field">
    <label>Username</label>
    <input placeholder="Username" name="username" type="text">
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <label>Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="password">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="field">
  <label>Skills</label>
  <select name="skills" multiple="" class="ui dropdown">
    <option value="">Select Skills</option>
    <option value="css">CSS</option>
    <option value="html">HTML</option>
    <option value="javascript">Javascript</option>
    <option value="design">Graphic Design</option>
    <option value="plumbing">Plumbing</option>
    <option value="mech">Mechanical Engineering</option>
    <option value="repair">Kitchen Repair</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="inline field">
  <div class="ui checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" name="terms">
    <label>I agree to the terms and conditions</label>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="ui blue submit button">Submit</div>
<div class="ui error message"></div>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You don't need to add the css and js file for form if you are already loading the whole `semantic.css` and `semantic.js` files

Comment: Try wrapping the `$('.ui.form')` initialization in a `$(document).ready(function);` . When you run this code. What errors are you getting in your console?

Comment: @A. de Guzman can you please check the answers - comment if you still have problems, accept it or share your solution? So it helps others and gives feedback if the answers are correct or at least help.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  // and here your code
});
```

as semantic needs jQuery to work so you have to call the semantic UI functions in jQuery.

Comment: hey, i missed () after the function. it will be `.ready(function(){` check out the documentation of jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

I was wondering about the answer of Ashish sah. So I created a Code Pen for your problem:

**[CodePen](https://codepen.io/pme123/details/VXGaQY/)**

This shows that the script must not be in `$(document).ready(..`

Strange is also that the code from the question works.

**Only difference** I see: Code Pen adds the Script dependency add the end of the body - not the head.

Comment: I think these editors add the script of their own. You just need to provide the link and as per the lib you add these editors add the code.